# How does on one create a circumplex model (multiple answers)?

Tags: emotion, measurement, data, task-analysis

Given a list of points with arousal and valence rankings, what is the best way of showing them on a circumplex model, given that they are already tagged with 1 out of 7 selected emotions, are they best plotted as a scatter plot with colors (should they also have lines connecting them to the "idea" locus) how should any groupings and variances be interpreted (knowing nothing about the data ahead of time) and what tools exist to do this already that do not need to be created from near scratch (there is no circumplex plot built into matlab)? Also, are there known absolute coordinates for any existing model as to where the labels go?